# Has anyone used android-adb Ruby gem?

Tags: android, ruby

Hi all has anyone used android-adb gem in ruby.
I basically want to run adb commands from a ruby script.I found this andoir-adb gem but I do not seem to find any documentation as to how to use this.
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I can see it's no longer maintained , have you check with the examples provided to get an idea about it ?
check this out http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/android-adb/AndroidAdb

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am getting parsing errors and i don think ruby 2.2 supports this.Is there any other gem to achieve what i need?

Comment: Is "yes" an acceptable answer?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland ..hahah nice one.On a serious note,If you have used it can you provide a baisc example?

Comment: https://github.com/cheezy/ADB try this , it has some documentation in it that can be helpful .

Comment: @Kiloreux Thank you I think this will help

Comment: I can post it as an answer if you want to close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the library mentioned by the OP is no longer maintained, and the documentation is lacking, i can suggest using the [ADB](https://github.com/cheezy/ADB) which has better docuementation .